# Create Elasticsearch mapping table in aws glue catalog

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-athena, aws-glue

Is it possible to create external table in aws glue catalog, which points to existing Elasticsearch index (e.g. aws elasticsearch server), as we can do it in Hive metastore?

And then insert data or read date from this table e.g. via aws Athena?

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/current/hive.html

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE my_db.my_es_ext_table (
   id string,
   text string,
   my_array array<string>,
   created_ts timestamp,
   year int,
   month int
)
STORED BY 'org.elasticsearch.hadoop.hive.EsStorageHandler'
TBLPROPERTIES(
   'es.nodes' = 'aws-host-to-es.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com', 
   'es.port' = '443' , 
   'es.resource' = 'my_jobs/myjob' , 
   'es.mapping.id' = 'id',
   'es.write.operation' = 'upsert',
   'es.nodes.wan.only' = 'true'
);
```